# Retrieving Document with a Collection in Firestore returning 'Encountered two children with same key` Error

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, collections

Here is what the structure of the initial collection looks like:

```
Messages (collection)
  - ADasjewj123asdej-SAasdadfsd1234 (document) // its one uid + '-' + other uid
    - chat (collection)
      - list of documents, etc.
```

I'm trying to retrieve all the documents within `Messages`, which has the custom indentifier, via:

```
 async getAllData(){
    let data = await firestore()
      .collection('Messages')
      .get()
    return data.docs.flat().map(doc => ({
      value: Object.values(doc.data()),
      key: doc.id  
    }))
  }
```

and it prompts the error; I've attempted various other methods based on the Firestore documentation, and its the same issue every time, could it be the custom identifier that the document uses?

thanks!

Comment: Can you post the snapshot of your DB instead of posting as plain text, because from the look of it, It looks like the collection name is `Data` rather than `Messages` So please edit the question while including the snapshot of your DB.

Comment: Hi does my posted answer help ? If so acknowledge it if not then we can solve it further.

Comment: Sorry, it is `Messsages` instead of `Data`, must have been a typo

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the way you are assigning the `doc.data()` to the `value` as error message "**Encountered two children with the same key**" typically occurs when you have duplicate keys within a document.

So I will recommend you to directly assign the `doc.data()` to the `value` without using `Object.values` as `doc.data()` is already in the Map form.

And as per your collection structure you provided it looks like your collection name is `Data` rather than `Messages`.

As per [**React Native Firebase**](https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage#read-data) your updated code should look something like this :

```
async getAllData() {
  let data = await firestore()
    .collection('Messages') // Update the collection name to 'Data' if that’s the case
    .get();

  return data.docs.map(doc => ({
    value: doc.data(),
    key: doc.id
  }));
}
```

Reference : [**React Native Firebase**](https://rnfirebase.io/)

Comment: Doesn't seem like its returning anything when logged in useEffect?